# How to hang plastic framed artwork?

Tags: hanging

This is a piece of mass-produced, commercial art. It came in a frame that's about an inch deep (it sticks maybe an inch off the wall, like a canvas wrapped around a wooden frame does). There is no hook/sawtooth/eyelet or anything else like that on the inside of the frame. How am I supposed to hang this on the wall?

And a sort of related question: is this meant to be put on the wall at all? I have seen a few other similar frame constructions, typically for mass-produced "Live Laugh Love" type artwork, where the frame sticks up off of the wall by about an inch and has no hooks or anything to hang it with, and the edge of the frame is too thin (less than a quarter of an inch) to drill anything through. Do people even put this stuff on the wall or do they just sort of lean it against things?

[image: front of frame]
[image: back of frame]

Comment: Where you bought it may well have clips etc - did you ask? I would have done so.

Comment: It was a gift. I'm in the cold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want it to hang like an old-fashioned painting or a modern wall decoration?

To hang like a painting, screw two eyelets about 2/3 to 3/4 of the way up each side of the frame [rear or inside edges will give different hanging angles], tie a string or wire between the two, with enough slack to be able to pull a triangle near to the inner top edge. Hang on a nail or picture hook.
This will swing it slightly forwards from the wall, just like a traditional painting. If it has a glass front, this is better for the lighting; you also aren't just gazing directly at your own reflection.

For a modern hang, just bang a panel pin into the wall, aiming downwards at 45° for optimum wall strength, leaving less than the frame's depth showing; & suspend the top of the frame from it. If it's a large piece or in a location prone to being knocked, use two pins near the outer edges. The advantage of panel pins is if you don't quite get them level, you can gently tap to bend the pins until it is. This will sit nicely flat to the wall.

I actually make & sell similar artwork - framed canvases - & that's how I usually mount mine. I much prefer them flush to the wall.

Examples -
Traditional hang vs modern hang

[image] [image]

I don't know the US term for a panel pin [from comments a 'finish nail'], but they are skinny lost-head nails. They are used for skirting board & similar. They're too small to ever split the wood [or plaster], have good penetration, but are really easy to bend if you hit them badly.
This one is quite long, 30mm is probably fine for a picture hanger.

[image]

Comment: For those of us on this side of the pond, care to define "panel pin"? I presume it's just a thin nail...

Comment: It is a skinny nail, lost head - let me see if I can find a picture with some idea of scale...

Comment: @FreeMan - dug one out of my drawer, added pic & description. If you know the transpondian name, feel free to edit it into the answer. :)

Comment: In the US, we'd call that a finish nail. That's probably a 2d. Funny, we're still using your antiquated naming conventions for describing nails in "penny".

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on modern hang vs traditional hang.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny screw-eyes exist.

Brads at an angle will also hold picture-hanging wire, if not quite as well.

Or go low and use staples.

You could probably loop a fine wire under the frame points holding the work in place, for a very minimalist hang.

You could also cut a groove in the top inside back frame to catch a nailhead or screwhead.

Or take it to a real framer to have a real frame that does not require fooling around installed. Or do that yourself...

Answer (score 1):

For those I would put two small screws or brads in the wall level and as far apart as about 80% - 90% of the picture width. Leave them out about 1/2" or more but not enough to keep the picture from being flat on the wall. Put them in pointing down at the wall about 20 degrees, that keeps the edge of the fastener on the inside of the frame. The picture should stay unless the wall moves. I cannot tell from the picture but if the frame is flat you can also use hook and loop to fasten it to the wall.